# Spring REST limit user access by user role

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have several user roles, let's say: user and admin.

I want to grant access to certain routes only to users with the **role of** admin. For example for this route:

```
@GetMapping("/all")
public ResponseEntity getAll(){
    List<User> users = this.userRepository.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How is it possible to create different middlewares in Spring so that I can use them to limit access to a certain user role?

Here is my User model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7643506746013338699L;

public User() { }

public User(String username, String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

@Id
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 5, max = 15)
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Email
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 5)
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

//some more user properties
...

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

// getters and setters
...
}
```

I have the JWT authentication implemented. Please let me know if I should upload it as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Look for the @PreAuthorize annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hasRole("ADMIN") on that route "/all" in spring security config 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver/src/main/java/sample/OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration.java

otherwise you can extract role from Jwt like so and test for the correct role:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver/src/main/java/sample/OAuth2ResourceServerController.java

Comment: what would be the difference in performance between these 2 aproaches?

Comment: You are better off using the first approach as it will prevent hitting the controller but there is only limited checks you can do there. If you want to do more complex business rules validation then you might want to do that in controller.